# $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently Im have the following script which checks to see if a checkbox value has changed but its not working when I try to use it!

```
<script>
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if ($(this).prev().attr('checked') && $(this).val() != $(this).prev().val()) {
                alert("previous checkbox has same value");
            }
        }
    });​
 </script>

 <input name="" type="checkbox" value="here"/>(if this was checked)
 <input name="" type="checkbox" value="here"/>(then this)
 <input name="" type="checkbox" value="there"/>(would not allow prompt alert) 
 <input name="" type="checkbox" value="here"/>(would allow)​
```

you can see it working here yet it does not work when i try to use it 
http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LgxPn/7

The idea is to alert when a checked checkbox value is different from the previously checked checkbox value!

Currently my checkbox look like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onClick="getVal();setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>"/>
```

I thought the function `('input[type=checkbox]').change(function()` would get these but im wrong somewhere?

Comment: Which browser? Using `.val()` on a checkbox can return either "true/false" or the "here/there" you have depending on the browser. I would suggest using `data-` attributes for the "value" part. I would also switch from `.change()` to `.click()`;

Comment: Your script isn't in a document ready call, that's probably part of the problem

Comment: Maybe you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Also no `type` attribute on the script.

Comment: @Cory Actually that's not required

Comment: simply switch the .attr() to .prop() @biziclop

Comment: @biziclop, remember `prop` is JQuery 1.6+ only

Comment: provide correct jsfiddle link

Comment: Working JSFiddle link, I assume: http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LgxPn/4/

Comment: try this whats going on jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/gy8EQ/2 @MikeRobinson

Comment: if i select the first box(there) and then another (here ) it works but if i select (here) and the (there) id doesnt alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the previous checked sibling checkbox, use this:

```
$(this).prevAll(":checked:first")
```

I expected to use `:last`, but `:first` is what works.  This is counter-intuitive to me and inconsistent with how `:first` and `:last` usually work, but I tested it in several browsers and the result is consistent.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var lastChecked = $(this).prevAll(":checked:first");
        if (this.value == lastChecked.val()) {
            alert("previous checked box has same value");
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LgxPn/15/

---

**Edit:** If by "previously checked checkbox" you mean the last box the user clicked, then you'll need to keep track of that yourself.  There's no built-in jQuery method that will tell you anything about click history.

What happens when the user first checks several boxes, and then checks and immediately unchecks a box?  Should the next most recently checked box be used?  If so, then you need to keep track of all checked boxes, and what order they were clicked.  Here's how you can keep track of the checked boxes:

```
var lastChecked = [];
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        if (lastChecked.length && this.value == lastChecked[0].value) {
            alert("the last box you checked has the same value");
        }
        lastChecked.unshift(this);
    }
    else {
        lastChecked.splice(lastChecked.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LgxPn/21/

Comment: The problem is it only works right to left try the other direction? Im also trying to do the opposite of your code if the value does not equal  if (this.value != lastChecked.val()) {
            alert("previous checked box has same value");
        }

Comment: @tyler - please edit your question to *clearly* state what you mean by "the previously checked checkbox".  See, your code implies you want the previous checkbox in the DOM, because you are trying to get it using `.prev()`.  But your comment seems to imply you want to get the last checkbox the user checked.  It's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: ahh know i see where i was confusing thanks so much! I do indeed mean previous selected NOT DOM! And your code seemed to work!Why does this not work when i paste it into my code? Im simply putting <html><head><script>the code here </script> </head><body><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onClick="getVal();setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>"/><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onClick="getVal();setChecks(this)" value="`key`=<?php echo $rspatient['key']?>" class="chk" id="chk<?php echo $a++?>"/>

Comment: @tyler - `this.checked = false` or `$(this).prop("checked", false)`

Comment: please read my above im pulling my hair out over this ill be honest its my first attempt at using Jquery and i dont understand im treating it as if it where javascript wrapping it in <script tags>Also note i have it working as i want in fiddle which is only adding to the frustration

Comment: You have to include jQuery.  jQuery is a JavaScript library.  Your page can only use that library if you include it on your page.  Above your `<script>` tag, insert another one that references jQuery.  Eg, `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/LgxPn/24/ I posted into the html section so you can get an idea of what i have

Comment: I tried this still no luck a link to where http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/test3.html im using chrome should this matter

Comment: Also, wrap your code in a document ready handler.  Ie, `$(function(){ /* your code here */ });`.  See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/LgxPn/26/

Comment: ok this is working but if i get the alert once for a value it wont happen again aka click 1 then 2 get alert (I put the code into uncheck the box So its unchecked) Now if i click 2 again no alert! Im sure its registering the last clicked as 2 now any idea how to fix!

Comment: @gilly3if (lastChecked.length && this.value != lastChecked[0].value) {
       $(this).prop("checked", false)
                            alert("the last box you checked has a different value");

Comment: i tried adding the following line after the alert displays $(this).value=lastChecked[0].value but this did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (with some better syntax), try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
       if ($(this).prev().prop('checked') && $(this).val() != $(this).prev().val()) { 
         alert("previous checkbox has same value");
       }
    }
  });​
});

</script>
```

Comment: Remember to use `prop` instead of `attr` if using JQuery 1.6+

Comment: tried this! also tired with attr and prop still no success @jaypeagi

Comment: @tyler as i mention in my solution, the issue at hand might be the `!=` in your `if` statement

Comment: try this whats going on jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/gy8EQ/2

Comment: if i select the first box(there) and then another (here ) it works but if i select (here) and the (there) id doesnt alert

Answer (score 0):

Your alert message and your `if` statement don't match. You check to see if the values `!=`, but the alert says they are equal. I'm assuming the alert is the case you want to check for. Try:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $prev = $this.prev();
  if($this.is(':checked')) {
    if($prev.is(':checked') && $this.val() === $prev.val()) {
      alert('Previous checkbox has same value');
    }
  }
});​
```

And as the others mentioned, make sure this is all within a `$(document).ready()` block

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(){
$(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
     if ($(this).prev().attr('checked') && $(this).val() != $(this).prev().val()) 
     alert("previous checkbox has same value");
   }
  });​
});
}

</script> ?

Comment: try this whats going on jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/gy8EQ/2

Comment: if i select the first box(there) and then another (here ) it works but if i select (here) and the (there) id doesnt alert

Comment: @tyler your jsfiddle demo is failing because the `onclick` events attached to your checkboxes isn't defined in the jsfiddle code. Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/gy8EQ/4/ It uses my solution and appears to function as you want it to

Comment: @tyler if you select the 2nd checkbox, and then the 1st, nothing will ever happen because the function looks for `.prev()`, and the first checkbox has no previous sibling

Comment: jack you are verry close but i want it to alert when diffrent! i chenger your code to != and it works from left to right but not right to left @jack

Comment: any idea how I could change my code work for this situation aswell

Comment: I want to compare the value of the last selected box to the just selected if its different alert the user

Comment: im confused as to why .prev() would be empty when checking 2boxes in a row regardless of the order

Comment: @tyler `.prev()` refers to the element's adjacent previous sibling in the DOM hierarchy. Are you trying to refer to the value of the previously selected checkbox (regardless of position in the DOM), because that would require a completely different solution

Comment: in that case, my suggestion would be to try again, with the understanding that to do what you want, you will need to manually maintain a reference to the last checkbox that was checked, and each time a checkbox is checked, compare to that reference. If you are still having issues, you can create a new question, but I think we've gotten too far from the nature of this question to continue here

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in Chrome:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if ($(this).prev().prop('checked')) {
                if ($(this).val() != $(this).prev('input[type=checkbox]').val()) {
                    alert("previous checkbox has same value");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

**Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gy8EQ/**

Comment: if i select the first box(there) and then another (here ) it works but if i select (here) and the (there) id doesnt alert

Comment: @tyler: So you want to look at ALL previous checkboxes? `prev()` only looks at the immediately adjacent sibling, not all of them. Change it to `prevAll()` to look at all adjacent siblings. You will have to change the code to loop over all previous checkboxes.

Comment: I want to compare the value of the last selected box to the just selected if its different alert the user

Comment: tried your fix but it didnt work! I get the warning when going from the 1st to the secont box but when trying the otherway 2nd then 1st nothing happens

Comment: @tyler: I think you're misunderstanding how `prev()` works, or I'm misunderstanding your intent. `prev()` finds the DOM element on the page immediately before the current one. Meaning: the previous element in the DOM structure, not which checkbox was most recently clicked.

Comment: Your right i was completely wrong! Any idea why this will not work http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/test3.html